# Tkinter - test create button, get command value

Tags: python, testing, tkinter, button, command

```
def create_new_button(root, button_text, function_for_button):
    return ttk.Button(root, text=button_text, command=function_for_button)

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_tkinter_toplevel_root():
    return Tk()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("text,function", (
            ("New buttton", lambda: None),
            ("", lambda: None),
            ("New button", None)
    ))
    def test_create_new_button(fixture_tkinter_toplevel_root, text, function):
        new_button = create_new_button(fixture_tkinter_toplevel_root, text, function)
    
        assert new_button.cget("text") ==  text
```

Hi, I have a question, testing whether tkinter.ttk.Button objects are created correctly. I can look at the "text" value and compare it with the declared value, but unfortunately I can't find how I can get the command value. _tclCommands stores it as a string. cget ("command") also returns the string itself, not the object. I am asking for help and feedback if you are more experienced and think that I should approach the code test differently.

Comment: You cannot get the function as a function object quite easily

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a fool, for my needs it is enough for me to compare the results. I return "None" so I get "None" ...

Comment: Oh, no probs :)